# When was the speed of a bullet or cannon ball first measured?

Tags: experimental-physics, projectile, history, speed

I see that prior to the invention of accurate clocks it might have been pretty hard and I wonder, just as with the speed of light, the speed of bullets was wildly over-estimated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about history not physics and would be more appropriate on [hsm.se].

Comment: @sammygerbil The title references history, but the content seems to ask about the process of the measurement, sort of a toss up.

Comment: @AdrianHoward I think that the issue in the body of the question (whether the speed of bullets was wildly over-estimated) can also only be answered by historical study and not by physics theory. For other reasons also (such as lack of clarity and context) I think the question deserves to be put on hold to give the user the opportunity to improve it before other answers are posted.

Answer (score 2):

With a telescope, the impingement point of a fired bullet or cannon ball can be observed at such a (measured) distance as to require several seconds of flight time on the part of the bullet. A crude clock that can measure ~seconds can then be used to get an *estimate* of the average speed of the bullet during its (long) flight, without having to accurately measure ~milliseconds as would be needed to measure its speed over a short baseline.